# Send Bulk emails as bcc in Drupal

Tags: views, 7

I am using Drupal 7. I have used [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module  to send an email, which is working fine. 
Now Problem is that email is going as **TO** , all other user are able to see other emails id.

I want to send as [Blind carbon copy (bcc)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy). Can anybody tell, how we can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do this by using [Blind Carbon Copy](https://www.drupal.org/project/bcc) module.

> The BCC module injects a BCC header in all e-mails sent by Drupal,
>   which allows you to receive copies of all e-mails sent by your
>   website.